# Loading freezes after kernel update

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I installed new kernel - 3.19 today, previous kernel is - `3.16.0-30-generic`. New kernel with the same configuration that was in previous and grub config is the same too..., instead of vmlinuz and initrd.

After rebooting

```
Loading Linux 3.19-generic ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
```

And nothing more. It just freezes after it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Load the 3.16 kernel and try rebuilding the initial ram disk:

```
update-initramfs -ck 3.19-generic
```

Look for any errors, if it builds cleanly, try rebooting into it again.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I built it before. The same result. There were no any errors when i built initrd image with update-initramfs.

Comment: Alright, have you tried putting some debug parameters in the grub line?  Also take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/InitramfsDebug.  A little outdated but I think it should still help.